# how to import wavesurfer in nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, wavesurfer.js

i want to use [wawesurfer](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) plugin for audio visualization in nuxt.js framework.

but i don't know how to import and use it?
my application is in universal(ssr) mode.

if i import it like this:

```
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';
```

its give me error that `windows is not defined`

if i create a plugin in plugin directory and import it and add it to nuxt.config.js in plugins section, it doesn't work and it's give me this error message:
`wawesurfer is not defined`

what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (process.browser) {
    var WaveSurfer = require('wavesurfer.js');
  }
```